# After connecting Log4j2 spring boot application throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I am new to programming. I have a `multi`-`module` application. After I excluded `spring-boot-starter-logging` in `POM.xml` and connecting `Log4j2`, `Spring Boot` application throws an exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException`.

Parent `POM.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.bogdan.pms</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project_Management_System</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>${revision}${changelist}</version>

  <modules>
    <module>PMS-App</module>
    <module>PMS-dto</module>
    <module>PMS-datalayer</module>
    <module>PMS-core</module>
    <module>PMS-web</module>
    <module>PMS-common</module>
  </modules>
  <properties>
    <revision>0.1</revision>
    <changelist>-SNAPSHOT</changelist>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.26</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>42.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

  
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
      <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.22.0</version>
    </dependency>

    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

   
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-spring-boot</artifactId>
      <version>2.20.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>1.17.6</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>project_management_system</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
          <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>4.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/project_management_system</url>
              <username>postgres</username>
              <password>*****</password>
              <outputChangeLogFile>db.changelog-master.xml</outputChangeLogFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <mainClass>com.bogdan.pms.Application</mainClass>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="LogToConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="LogToFile" fileName="logs/app.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.bogdan" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.springframework.boot" level="error" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

After launching the application:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.0)

14:38:44.491 [main] INFO  com.bogdan.pms.Application - Starting Application using Java 17.0.7 with PID 5256 (D:\IT\DigDes\ProjectManagementSystem\PMS-App\target\classes started by Bogdan in D:\IT\DigDes\ProjectManagementSystem)
DEBUG StatusConsoleListener AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy=UNCACHED (user specified null, default is UNCACHED)
DEBUG StatusConsoleListener org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.SystemClock supports precise timestamps.
14:38:44.548 [main] DEBUG com.bogdan.pms.Application - Running with Spring Boot v3.1.0, Spring v5.3.24
14:38:44.550 [main] INFO  com.bogdan.pms.Application - No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
14:38:44.814 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/NestedIOException
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:323) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733) [spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435) [spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) [spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1305) [spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1294) [spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at com.bogdan.pms.Application.main(Application.java:14) [classes/:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[?:?]
    ... 13 more
DEBUG StatusConsoleListener Stopping LoggerContext[name=6f94fa3e, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@2ca26d77]...
DEBUG StatusConsoleListener Shutting down FileManager logs/app.log
DEBUG StatusConsoleListener OutputStream closed
DEBUG StatusConsoleListener Shut down FileManager logs/app.log, all resources released: true
DEBUG StatusConsoleListener Appender LogToFile stopped with status true
DEBUG StatusConsoleListener Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false
DEBUG StatusConsoleListener OutputStream closed
DEBUG StatusConsoleListener Shut down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false, all resources released: true
DEBUG StatusConsoleListener Appender LogToConsole stopped with status true
DEBUG StatusConsoleListener Stopped XmlConfiguration[location=D:\IT\DigDes\ProjectManagementSystem\PMS-web\target\classes\log4j2.xml] OK
DEBUG StatusConsoleListener Stopped LoggerContext[name=6f94fa3e, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@2ca26d77] with status true

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I hope I provided enough information. I will be glad for any help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: All code was working fine until I decided to install log4j2.what specifically is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical issue when dependencies are not compatible with each other. I think the log4j2 dependency added is not compatible with the version of spring you are using.

You might want to analyze the dependencies to see the conflicting maven dependencies.

I have done it using the [Dependency Analyzer](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tutorials/analyzing-dependencies/dependency-analyzer/) in intelliJ and it is not looking good.

[image: Conflicting dependencies]

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but I've never experienced anything like this. I would be grateful if you tell me what I need to do?
Manually fix all version conflicts?